# The use of the string method charAt() to search for character in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a problem that requires me to use charAt in javascript.
The problem briefly, ask me to build a form that enables the users to enter several lines of text and then search for character using String and charAt, to determine the number of occurrence of the search character. The result will be display in a text area. If the character is not found within the search then display within a new window using window.open method, with a massage like: "Search character not found in text string!"

I came up with the following code but it doesn't actually work and I'm a bit confused of what went wrong!

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>search using string method</title>

</head>

<body onload="document.getElementById('key').focus();">

<section class="body">
        <h3>Object Exercise Solution 3 - charAt() - Mary had a little lamb</h3>

      <form name="myForm">
         
         <p>Enter a character to search for
            <textarea name="key" rows="3" cols="60" autofocus>
</textarea><br><br>   
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="search();">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="document.forms['myForm'].elements['key'].focus();">
</p>
         <br><br>
         
<h3>Occurrences of each digit entered above:</h3>
<textarea name="output" rows="14" cols="23" readonly></textarea>
      </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<script>

function search()
         {
            var count=0;

            var key = document.getElementById("key").value.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
             var key = key.toLowerCase();

            var stringToSearch=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
            "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
            var stringToSearch=stringToSearch.toLowerCase(); 


             for (i=0; i < stringToSearch.length; i++)
                     {

                    if (stringToSearch.charAt(i) == key)
                             count++;     
                     }         

            if ( count == 0 )
               document.getElementById("output").value=key + " not found";
            else
               document.getElementById("output").value=count + 
                  " occurrence(s) of " + key + " found";
         }
</script>
```

This is my first time writing a question to "stack overflow" I hope I'm clear and using the right format!
Please let me know if you can help!

Comment: The question is not clear , you have written `search for character` but which character you want to search . Also there is `document.getElementById("key").value.toLowerCase().charAt(0);` do you want to search for the number of occurence of the first character?

Comment: `var stringToSearch=stringToSearch.toLowerCase();` ...  stringToSearch is an Array, which has no `toLowerCase` method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First:** I have added `id ="key"`

```
<textarea id ="key" name="key" rows="3" cols="60" autofocus>
</textarea><br><br>
```

as you used `document.getElementById('key').focus()` the code will try to find element with id with is not defined in html.

Also, `document.getElementById("output").value` will not find any element as the element with the id not exists. So, changed the following:

```
<textarea id = "output" name="output" rows="14" cols="23" readonly></textarea>
```

**Second:** The search function is not updated properly, please check the updated search function. Also, some code I put as comments as it will not work as snippet, uncomments the code from snippet to use.

> The working code snippet is given below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>search using string method</title>

</head>
<script>function search()
         {
            var count={};

            var key = document.getElementById("key").value.toLowerCase();
             var key = key.toLowerCase();

            var stringToSearch=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
            "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
            var stringToSearch=stringToSearch.join('').toLowerCase(); 

           for(var j = 0; j < key.length;j++) {
            var checkChr = key[j];
             for (i=0; i < stringToSearch.length; i++)
                     {
                    if(!count[stringToSearch.charAt(i)]) {
                      count[stringToSearch.charAt(i)] = 0;
                    }
                    if (stringToSearch.charAt(i) == checkChr)
                             count[stringToSearch.charAt(i)]++;     
                     }
             }

            for (i = 0; i < stringToSearch.length; i++)
            if ( count[stringToSearch.charAt(i)] == 0 )
               document.getElementById("output").value= document.getElementById("output").value + stringToSearch.charAt(i) + " not found\n";
            else
               document.getElementById("output").value=document.getElementById("output").value + count[stringToSearch.charAt(i)] + 
                  " occurrence(s) of " + stringToSearch.charAt(i) + " found\n";
                  alert(document.getElementById("output").value);

//Use the commented line in your real code.
                  //var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    //myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById("output").value);
         }</script>
<body onload="document.getElementById('key').focus();">

<section class="body">
        <h3>Object Exercise Solution 3 - charAt() - Mary had a little lamb</h3>

      <form name="myForm">
         
         <p>Enter a character to search for
            <textarea id ="key" name="key" rows="3" cols="60" autofocus>
</textarea><br><br>   
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="search();">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="document.forms['myForm'].elements['key'].focus();">
</p>
<br><br>
         
<h3>Occurrences of each digit entered above:</h3>
<textarea id = "output" name="output" rows="14" cols="23" readonly></textarea>
      </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Downvoter, would you please checking the working snippet of the answer?

Comment: Thank you. I got it now!